# Resource.Designer.cs generator missing resources on Debug

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

My IDE is showing errors complaining that my resources do not contain a definition, one example is:

```
'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'screen_padding'
```

The auto-generated Resource.Designer.cs file in the Resources folder of my Android project has the resources there, but it appears that there is another auto-generated Resource.Designer.cs file in the debug folder for my project, which for reasons unknown to me, is different and I guess is what is causing the error warnings. I'm having to copy/paste from the first in to the second to supress the error warnings (which are non-breaking), but they are annoying.

Is there any way round this, or why does the debug REsource.Designer file not mirror the Resource.Designer file in the project?

Comment: Try that, clean the solution, delete the bin and obj folders, open the Resource.Designer.cs in the Resources folder and modify it (delete or add a bunch of lines), then try to build the project again. I did that a couple of times and worked for me!

Comment: Can you try to set `<AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>False</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>` in your .csproj? We have fixed this issue, but it is inside 15.8: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1784

Answer (score 3):

You should put this inside of your .csproj file: `<AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>False</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>`.

To do that, close your project, open the .csproj file and insert it into the first `<PropertyGroup>`. I inserted right after `<MonoAndroidAssetPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetPrefix>`.

Comment: Why do I still use Xamarin? So many absolutely random problems all the time.  Thank you.