# "Resource" does not contain a definition for "Xml"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-resources

Following the [Android PreferenceFragmetCompat docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) I added a folder to my Resources folder in my Xamarin.Android project. Then I added a new .xml file to that folder, called `preferences.xml`.

Here are the contents of that file:

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
          android:key="pref_autosync"
          android:title="@string/pref_autosync"
          android:summary="@string/pref_autosync_summary" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Both strings are properly defined in the `strings.xml` file.

I went on to add a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` to my project, in which, in the overriden method `OnCreatePreferences` I added the following line:

```
SetPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);
```

The error states `'Resource' does not contain a definiton for 'Xml'`.

I tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding my project
- Restartng Visual Studio
- Restarting my computer
- Deleting the contents of both the `bin` and `obj` folders, cleaning and rebuilding
- Changing the `CustomTool` property of the `preferences.xml` file to `MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles` and rebuilding
- Screaming with frustration

I am aware that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219973/resource-contains-no-definition-for-animation/33228113#33228113) thread exists, and I tried all the solutions mentioned there. Nothing seems to help.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The error is frustrating and many people have this issue, but if it is not stopping you build your project the error can be ignored.

Comment: @uprightbassfan78 The problem is it is stopping my build. I had to comment out the line before rebuilding.
Also, if many people have this issue, do you have any links I could read up on?

Comment: Have you looked in your ResourceDesigner.cs to see if preferences is defined under Xml?

Comment: @uprightbassfan78 That's quite interesting, in the `Resouce.designer.cs` file there is a `public partial class Xml`. Inside there's a `public const int preferences`. However, the error persists. There's also the second `Resource.Designer.cs` file located in `obj\debug\designTime`. That one doesn't contain the `Xml` class. I'll also mention that they are both in the same namespace.

Comment: @uprightbassfan78 Holy Cow, I didn't expect the second comment thing to actually work, but it did. I'm going to post an answer to your question, and you can post to mine for some rep :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059653/resource-designer-cs-generator-missing-resources-on-debug?noredirect=1#comment89122278_51059653